# Infeasible solution by pulp

Tags: python, pulp

I am using the pulp library to solve a Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP), but infeasible solutions are obtained with this library. When I solve the same problem with another solver, the optimal solution is obtained. In this case, I think probably there is a syntax error.
The main part of the model is as follows:

```
set_J = range(nStops, 1) # nStop is the number of cities and set_J is the related set.
trips = LpVariable.dicts(name="trips", indexs=set_I, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger) # trips is the decision variable
prob = LpProblem("TSP_MIP", LpMinimize) # Model definition
prob += lpSum(dist[i]*trips[i] for i in set_I) # Objective function
prob += lpSum(trips[i] for i in set_I) == nStops, "" # Constraint 1
# Constraint 2:
for j in set_J:
    prob += lpSum(trips[whichIdxs[i, j]] for i in set_I) == 2, ""
prob.solve()
```

The result is as:

At line 2 NAME MODEL

At line 3 ROWS

At line 6 COLUMNS

At line 8 RHS

At line 10 BOUNDS

At line 12 ENDATA

Problem MODEL has 1 rows, 1 columns and 0 elements

Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors

***Empty problem - 1 rows, 1 columns and 0 elements
Empty problem - 1 rows, 1 columns and 0 elements***

***Primal infeasible - objective value 0***

***PrimalInfeasible objective 0 - 0 iterations time 0.002***

***Result - Linear relaxation infeasible***

Enumerated nodes:           0

Total iterations:           0

Time (CPU seconds):         0.01

Time (Wallclock Seconds):   0.01

*Please give your opinion.*